# "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" and thread pool

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, exception

I am using a ThreadPool in order to run the same method several times at the same times.
I have a TextBox in MainWindow.xaml called OUTPUT_Box, and a class called HTTP_Web.
When I try to edit OUTPUT_BOX.Text from HTTP_Web.cs, I get the above exception. So far the solution is simple:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    OUTPUT_BOX.Text += "ALL OK";
}));
```

But when I use it, nothing happens.
The whole code:

```
public void ThreadsPool(string arg)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ACTION), someargument);
}

private void ACTION(object arg)
{
//.. Some code
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    OUTPUT_BOX.Text += "ALL OK";
}));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which line you get the exception? I guess your `//.. Some code` access the UI, which is not allowed when this method is called from thread pool thread. Also starting from .Net 4.0 there is no need to use `QueueUserWorkItem`, use TPL. Assuming you're in .Net 4.0 or higher.

Comment: I am not getting any exception, nothing happens, the TextBox isn't updated. And I'm developing for 3.5 also.

Comment: if you put breakpoint maybe something will happen and you could ask the question then?

Comment: In your question you said *I get the above exception*, and now you're saying *I am not getting any exception*. Which is true ? If there is no exception then where does this message comes from *The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it” and thread pool* ?

Comment: I tried, still nothing.

Comment: Siriam, I'll explain myself better: at first I got the above exception. Then I used the Dispatcher, and then I stop getting the exception, but nothing happened.

Comment: UI elements must be updating from the UI thread. I would use the debugger to check which thread you are using to update `Text`

Comment: Just delete Dispatcher word

Comment: I can assure you that none of the UI elements are updated until the code inside the Dispatcher. Reniuz - I don't understand your meaning

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something which is intentionally difficult to do (Notice that the dispatcher is hidden from intelisense)

WPF is written to work with data binding, and thus you never have to worry about access on the UI thread.

To this end, the MVVM pattern came into being, which splits an application into distinct components. Once you get your head round this pattern, WPF makes a lot more sense and works a lot more easily and you never (well, rarely anyway!) need to worry about the UI thread access ever again!

Comment: So there is no way to edit a TextBox content from a ThreadPool method? Can you think of anything else?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: What you're doing should work. Put some break points in to see if ACTION is getting called, and another to see if the line that sets .text is called as well